# How to get words one per one from .txt file to string

Tags: c++, file-management

Im a begginer c++ programer and i wanted to do one project by myself, im trying to make Login nad Register system with userdatabase thats in .txt format. I did everything exept one thing, when a person has registered and wants to login, i dont know how to check in userdatabase.txt if the username and password that they are entering is in there or they need to register first. Instead of that it just logins them. Can somebody help me ill be so grateful.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    izbor: 
    cout << "Izbor: " ;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1. Prijava" ;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "2. Registracija" ;
    cout << endl;
    int izbor;
    cin >> izbor;
 
if(izbor == 2){

int password, password2; 
string username;
cout << "Da bi se registrovali, potrebno je da unesete: " ;
ponovni_unos:
cout << endl;
cout << "  Korisnicko ime: ";
cin >> username;
cout << endl;
cout << "  Sifru: ";
cin >> password;
cout << endl;
cout << "  Molimo vas da potvrdite sifru: ";
cin >> password2;
cout << endl;
    if (password == password2){
    fstream file;
    file.open("UserData\\userdatabase.txt" , ios :: in | ios :: out | ios :: trunc);
    file.close();
    file.open("UserData\\userdatabase.txt" , ios :: in | ios :: out );
    file << username;
    file << password;
    file.close();
    cout<< "Uspjenso ste se registrovali!";
    cout << endl;
}
    else if(password != password2){
    cout<< "Sifra se ne podudara, molimo vas ponovo upisite sifru." ;
    cout << endl;
    goto ponovni_unos;
} 
    goto kraj;
}
else if(izbor == 1){

int password;
string username;
cout << "Prijava:" ;
cout << endl;
cout << "  Korisnicko ime: ";
cin >> username;
cout << endl;
cout << "  Sifra: ";
cin >> password;
cout << endl;

   // ifstream file;
   // file.open ("UserData\\userdatabase.txt");
   // if (!file.is_open()) return;

   // string word;
   // while (file >> word)            // i tried this but it doesnt work
   // {
   // cout<< word << '\n';
   // }
   // cout<< "Uspjenso ste se prijavili!";
   // cout << endl;
   // goto kraj;
}
 else{

    cout<< "Molimo vas izaberite opciju 1. ili 2.!";
    cout << endl;
    goto izbor;
}
kraj:
cout<< "Uzivajte u nasem programu.";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Keep indentation perfect and do not use `goto`.  It helps a lot if you do both those things..

Comment: What is the format of your `.txt` file? Do you have one string per line? Is the first line the username of the first user? Is the second line the password of the first user? And is the third line the username of the second user? Please show us the contents of the file, or at least a sample.